# What does 'Template error at line 0' mean in django?

Tags: python, django

I have got an error on a django site that i am working on which is a zero division error. I couldn't find the source of the error which I am thinking that is because of likely mathfilter but still not sure.

What I am asking here is that django gives that error with saying it occurs at line 0 which I don't know what that exactly mean.

This is the beginning of the template file:

```
1   {% extends "main.html" %}
2   {% include "ru.html" %}
3   {% load staticfiles %}
4   {% load mathfilters %}
5   {% load humanize %}
```

Only thing that occurs to me when I see this (error at line 0) is that to look at the main.html file. But I couldn't find anything that might cause this zero division error.

- How to debug?
- What might cause this error?
- What does error at line 0 means and which file should i debug then?
- Which filters might cause this?
- Any possible version problem?

Comment: Remove everything and start adding back lines one by one until you reproduce the error. Then yiu'll know what line is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, this has nothing to deal with *divide by zero*, this is a *reverse URL* misfunction.

While debugging, I had different line numbers : 0, 13, 15, etc… each time the line mentioned had no bad reverse URL call.

I had this message :

```
Error during template rendering
In template …project/templates/base.html, error at line 0

Reverse for 'search' not found. 'search' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How I solve it :

1. Open all templates concerned by the URL which gives me this message
2. Search over files where I use `search`, specially in a `{% url 'search' %}` tag
3. Rename tag by the good URL name (defined in the app `url.py`), in my case it was `foo-search`)

Comment: For me, it was a trailing whitespace in the text-string literal for the name of the URL pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Exception ZeroDivisionError is raised when the second argument of a division or modulo operation is zero.There must be such expression in your "main.html" file or other files that link it.Post your main.html code so that I could figure out.

Comment: there is a block called {% block main_wrapper %} which 8 or 9 template usese that block.So ı mnot sure it might easy to solv .But i want to ask that isin't there any way to see that this error comes from a spesific block inside spesific template?It give general error like i explained above.

Comment: In the trackback section of your error page there will be the highlighted portion of code.it is were the error is

Comment: Yes.but it only shows the filter and django files,no code we wrote.